# Retrieve secrets from AWS Secrets Manager

Tags: json, linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, aws-cli

I have a bunch of secrets (key/value) pairs stored in AWS Secrets Manager. I tried to parse the secrets using `jq` as:

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id <secret_bucket_name> | jq --raw-output '.SecretString' | jq -r .PASSWORD
```

It retrieves the value stored in `.PASSWORD`, but the problem is I not only want to retrieve the `value` stored in `key` but also want to retrieve the key/value in the following manner:

```
KEY_1="1234"
KEY_2="0000"
.
.
.
so on...
```

By running the above command I am not able to parse in this format and also for every key/value I have to run this command many times which is tedious. Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't related to python, but more related to behaviour of aws cli and jq. I come up with something like this.

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id <secret_name> --output text --query SecretString | jq ".[]"
```

There are literally hundred different ways to format something like this.

aws cli itself has lot of options to filter output using `--query` option https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html

Exact conversion you are looking for would require somwthing like this:

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id <secret_name> --output text --query SecretString \
 | jq  -r 'to_entries[] | [.key, "=", "\"", .value, "\"" ] | @tsv' \
 | tr -d "\t"
```

There has to be some better way of doing this!!

Comment: I need the values to be printed as it is they're stored in AWS secrets manager. This command is working but it is putting an extra `""` quotation marks. Example: Stored value in secrets manager is something like this...

`KEY_1    "XXXX"`

but when running this command it is giving output like this...

`KEY_1=""XXXX""`

How to avoid these extra quotation marks?

Comment: You can remove additional quotes `"\""` I added to command  and keep it just `[.key, "=",  .value ]`

Answer (score 3):

Try the snippet below. I tend to put these little helper filters into their own shell function <3

```
tokv() {
  jq -r 'to_entries|map("\(.key|ascii_upcase)=\"\(.value|tostring)\"")|.[]'
}

$ echo '{"foo":"bar","baz":"fee"}' | tokv
FOO="bar"
BAZ="fee"
```